# Does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac23}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac23}}$ converges or diverges.

P. S.: I know it looks bad but help me, please.

Comment: Hint:  comparison test.

Comment: @ElizabethHan That cannot be used as the series isn't a positive one.

Comment: Write out the first few terms and notice division by zero.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oops, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\left(\frac1{n^{2/3}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is is decreasing and converges to $0$. You can use the [Alternating series test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).